# UI is not updating while viewModel is updated in android kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, viewmodel

I am following the MVVM pattern Activity-->ViewModel ---> Repository . Repository is calling api and updated the LiveData. The value is of LiveData is also updated in ViewModel but its not reflecting on Activity. Please guide me where i am missing, Code is given below

Activity code:

```
class LoginWithEmailActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private var loginViewModel: LoginViewModel? = null
    private var binding: ActivityLoginWithEmailBinding? = null
    private var btnLogin : Button? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
       
        loginViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(LoginViewModel::class.java)

        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this@LoginWithEmailActivity, R.layout.activity_login_with_email)
        binding!!.setLifecycleOwner(this)
        binding!!.setLoginViewModel(loginViewModel)
        btnLogin = findViewById(R.id.btn_login)

        loginViewModel!!.servicesLiveData!!.observe(this, Observer<LoginDataModel?> { serviceSetterGetter ->

            val msg = serviceSetterGetter.success
            Toast.makeText(this@LoginWithEmailActivity, ""+msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            Log.v("///LOGIN SUCCESS////",""+msg);
           
        })
        btnLogin!!.setOnClickListener {
            loginViewModel!!.getUser()

        }
}
```

ViewModel.kt

```
class LoginViewModel : ViewModel() {
    var servicesLiveData: MutableLiveData<LoginDataModel>? = MutableLiveData()

    fun getUser() {
        servicesLiveData = MainActivityRepository.getServicesApiCall()
    }
}
```

Repository.kt

```
object MainActivityRepository {

    val serviceSetterGetter = MutableLiveData<LoginDataModel>()

    fun getServicesApiCall(): MutableLiveData<LoginDataModel> {
        val params = JsonObject()
        params.addProperty("email", "xyz@gmail.com")
        val call: Call<LoginDataModel> = ApiClient.getClient.getPhotos(params)

        call.enqueue(object : Callback<LoginDataModel> {

            @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<LoginDataModel>?, response: Response<LoginDataModel>?) {
                if (response != null) {
                    val data = response.body()
                    serviceSetterGetter?.postValue(data);
                   
                }
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<LoginDataModel>?, t: Throwable?) {
            }

        })
        return serviceSetterGetter
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You subscribe to the LiveData in onCreate

```
loginViewModel!!.servicesLiveData!!.observe(this, Observer<LoginDataModel?> { serviceSetterGetter ->

            val msg = serviceSetterGetter.success
            Toast.makeText(this@LoginWithEmailActivity, ""+msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            Log.v("///LOGIN SUCCESS////",""+msg);
           
        })
```

but then `getUser` creates a new reference

```
fun getUser() {
    servicesLiveData = MainActivityRepository.getServicesApiCall()
}
```

The one you are subscribed to is not the same as the getUser liveData.

If you want to keep what you have mostly the same you need to use [MediatorLiveData](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/MediatorLiveData.html)

Or just do

```
getUser().observe(this, Observer<LoginDataModel?> { serviceSetterGetter ->

    val msg = serviceSetterGetter.success
    Toast.makeText(this@LoginWithEmailActivity, ""+msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    Log.v("///LOGIN SUCCESS////",""+msg);
           
})

fun getUser(): LiveData<LoginDataModel> {
    return MainActivityRepository.getServicesApiCall()
}
```

Comment: But by this way when i click button once log message prints once but again i press button log message prints twice and if i again press button log message prints thrice. Please guide me on this.

Comment: Which way are you talking about?

Comment: Toast.makeText(this@LoginWithEmailActivity, ""+msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        Log.v("///LOGIN SUCCESS////",""+msg);
        
        these messages are printing multiple times when user clicks login button

Comment: ok but I gave you two solutions, which one are you talking about? Personally I would just move to use the second option

Comment: I used this ---- >   getUser().observe(this, Observer<LoginDataModel?> { serviceSetterGetter ->

    val msg = serviceSetterGetter.success
    Toast.makeText(this@LoginWithEmailActivity, ""+msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    Log.v("///LOGIN SUCCESS////",""+msg);
           
})

fun getUser(): LiveData<LoginDataModel> {
    return MainActivityRepository.getServicesApiCall()
} , ---------------->>>>          when i use the second solution i get messages are printing multiple times when user clicks login button

Comment: Move your LiveData creation into your getServicesApiCall()

Comment: Thanks a lot , now its working. Thanks once again.!!!